# what is the best approach to store database row into html5 web storage and not web sql database

Tags: html, local-storage

We would like to evaluate the size of our data after storing it in html5 web storage. Our data is fetched from database.What would be the best way to store data from database into Html5 Web Storage. We know that HTML5 Web SQL Database is deprecated and dont want to use that option.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you read one of the thousands of tutorials available for using HTML5 localStorage?

Comment: Yes, may be I dint phrase my question properly. How would I store a database row to key value pair. Do I need to convert database row to JSON object and then store in local storage?

Comment: That would be a good option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the best solution is to set that value as JSON.

```
 var objectValue = JSON.stringify({name:"John",lastname:"Doe", other:"other staff"});//NOTE: your form data  
if (typeof (sessionStorage) !== "undefined") {

           if (sessionStorage.keyForStore ) {
                  try {
                       //sessionStorage.key = objectValue;
                       sessionStorage.setItem(keyForStore , objectValue);
                     } catch (e) {
                       console.log("LIMIT REACHED:");
                        console.log(e);
                   }
              }

   }
```

and when you read it

```
var objData = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.keyForStore );
console.log(objData.name)//etc..
```

Comment: you can check size of js object with this code( memorySizeOfObject.js):https://gist.github.com/zensh/4975495

Comment: Perfect. Let me try it and will let you know.

Comment: if you are not able to implement the code above I will update answer with included getter and setter methods

Comment: I was able to implement the code and the moment the size of data reaches around 4.2 MB, the javascript code for setting the key/value pair is not being called and the localstorage was not set. Im successfully able to store around 4700 database rows. My expectation would be to hit the catch block when data size exceeds . Why isnt it hitting the catch block?

Comment: Hi try something like this for testig : try {
  for(i = 0; i< 100000000;i++){
  localStorage.setItem(i+"dsd", "dsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdfdfdsfdfdfdsfds");
    }
} catch(domException) {
  if (domException.name === 'QuotaExceededError' ||
      domException.name === 'NS_ERROR_DOM_QUOTA_REACHED') {
   
    console.log('quota eceedede: ' + i)
  }
}

Comment: This still dint work. The code never went into catch block. But I was able to figure out the size of our data and how much could be stored in local storage.